# QT : Cannot find moc file

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to create a test application in QT to test another QT application's UI using qtlib. I learned that you also need to use  QTEST_MAIN() macro which expands to a simple main() method that runs all the test functions.

```
QTEST_MAIN(TestAppUI)
#include "testapp.moc"
```

I'm compiling it using "make" and somewhere in my CMakeLists.txt I have

```
SET(TEST_APP_SRCS
ui/menu/testapp.cpp
)

SET(TEST_APP_SRCS_MOC_SRCS
ui/menu/testapp.hpp
)

QT4_WRAP_CPP(TEST_APP_SRCS ${TEST_APP_SRCS_MOC_SRCS})
```

My problem is, during compilation I'm getting this error.
    error: testapp.moc: No such file or directory

I don't know what's wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: The building process is not able to create testapp.moc from testapp.hpp. Are you sure that the "moc" utility is in your path?

Comment: The other files in my project have no problems with moc... I just added this file and would like to have a separate executable for it... but it's giving me this error... :(

Comment: Did u add *that* file in your project? I mean in your `.pro` file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured what's wrong. I needed to add  ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTTEST_LIBRARY} in TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ... :) and remove #include "testapp.moc"

Comment: For me it also worked, to simply remove that '#include "[myfile].moc"' line

Comment: @Owen, could you mention whats there in QT_LIBRARIES & QT_TEST_LIBRARY variables?

Comment: I am facing same issue but if I delete '#include <MyTest.moc> file', I get error for undefined reference for vtable for MyTest.

Comment: If you have 2 files for your test (.cpp and .h) you have to remove the include for the .moc.